# Detaching Entities in EF4 - losing object graph

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

As other questions have noted, when you detach and re-attach an object, any child objects are gone.  I thought doing this:

```
db.Properties.MergeOption = System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
```

would cause subsequent reads to fully repopulate the object and graph when it was read in, but no such luck.  Is there any way to get this to work?

Specifically, I'd like to be able to detach an object, then re-read the object in from the database with the child objects all there.

Comment: If you are trying to re-attach it, why dont you just fetch the entity using "include" to get the child properties you want? Then it should be in the context for you to do whatever you want ("which I'm not sure what that is")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new backup object for the reload (perhaps using a new context), then move all the child objects and attach them to the new one?

If you're using Code First there are additional easier options.